# Selenium WebDriver get returns: "unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My error goes like this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}

The get command is `driver.get("https://www.google.com")`.

My Chrome version is 62, chromedriver version is 2.32, Windows 10.

Comment: The other ways that I tried were: 1. driver.get("https://"+"www.google.com");            2. String URL = "www.google.com";
  driver.get("https://"+URL);

Comment: You might want to say what you are actually trying to do... :)

Comment: I am just trying to reach google homepage, through webdriver. Apart from the webdriver initialization, GET command is the only line in my code. Once I run my code, Chrome is being invoked but with a blank page. And the error in eclipse is as stated in my question.

Comment: I really do not what is causing this issue. But creating a new work space altogether for the test scripts solved this issue.